# How can I assign default values to an array in Angular when the data is loaded dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, radio-group

I have an Array called 'habits'. like this
[image]

I show it in a table with radio buttons (yes, no).

[image]

```
 <tr *ngFor="let habits of masterDate.data.habits; index as x">
    <th class="tbl-border-right-bottom text-wrap" style="width: 50%">
        {{ habits.name }}
        <div hidden="true">
            <input type="text" formControlName="habitsSufferedMainId{{ x }}" />
        </div>
    </th>
    <td class="tbl-border-right-bottom">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-around pr-2">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}" value="1" name="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}" formControlName="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}" />
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                    <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="isMainHabitNo{{ x }}" value="0" name="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}" formControlName="habitsSufferedMain{{ x }}" [checked]="true" />
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="isMainHabitNo{{ x }}">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea placeholder="If 'Yes' please give details" class="form-control form-control-sm" rows="2" formControlName="habitsSufferedMainReason{{ x }}"></textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

1. How to set the default value to "No".

Comment: Hi! Can you post your JS? Looks like you're using Reactive Forms so you'd set your default values there.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @LawrenceJobI `this.policyService.getMasterData().subscribe((data2) => {
      let x = 0;
      data2.data.habits.forEach((element) => {
        this.lifeStyleFormGroup.addControl(
          "habitsSufferedMain" + x,
          new FormControl(false)
        );` have created FormControl like this.
But the default value is not set

Comment: See that you give value to your formControls true/false, and your radio value are 0 and 1, use `<input type="radio" [value]="true">` (or `<input type="radio" [value]="1">`, and **REMOVE** the `[checked]="true"`. When you have a FormControl, is the FormControl value who indicate if checked or not. NOTE: enclosed the value between `[` `]` makes angular get the value, else get a "string"

Answer (score 0):

First create a map to store the results

```
const results = new Map<number, boolean>();
```

You can set the default value of the checkbox using the FormControl()

```
 const habitOne = new FormControl(false);
 results['habitOne'].set(false);
```

Then listen to the valueChanges obserbable to store the result in a Map

```
habitOne.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    results.set('habitOne', value)
})
```

Of course you can do this with a loop using the FormBuilder. (But remeber to wrap all the inputs in a reactive form `<form [formGroup]=form>`

```
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group(
      this.habits.reduce((controls, habit, index) => {
        this.results.set(index, false)
        return {
        ...controls,
        [`habit${index}`]: new FormControl(false)
      }
    }, {}));

    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((control, index) => {
        control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
            this.results.set(index, value == true)
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.policyService.getMasterData().subscribe((data2) => {
      let x = 0;
      data2.data.habits.forEach((element) => {
       this.lifeStyleFormGroup.addControl(
          "habitsSufferedMain" + x,
          new FormControl(false)
        );`
I have created FormControl like this.
But the default value is not set

Comment: it would be helpful to have a stackbliz

Comment: I created [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgheq1?file=src%2Fmain.ts)